# NSPredicate on collection of an NSManagedObject fail to request

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nspredicate

I try to do the following:

```
    predicate = NSPredicate(format: "user.userID = %@ AND messages[SIZE] > 0", IOSUser.sharedInstance().userID)
    let managedObjectCtx = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Session", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectCtx)
    fetchRequest.entity = entity
    fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
    let dateSortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "messages[LAST].date", ascending: false)
    let sortDescriptors = [dateSortDescriptor]
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = sortDescriptors
    sessionFetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: managedObjectCtx, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
    sessionFetchedResultsController.delegate = self

do{
  try sessionFetchedResultsController.performFetch()
}catch{
  abort()
}
```

But it crashes on the performFetch().

Basically I try to get all chat Sessions owned by the user of the app and I try to be sure that all sessions have at least 1 message.
Also, I want to sort all sessions by most recent messages.

Here is the crash:

[image]

Comment: I tried to add     fetchRequest.includesSubentities = true
but it still fails

Comment: I tried also with the keyword "ANY"     AND ANY messages[SIZE] > 0"

Comment: Are you sure the predicate is the problem - I suspect it might be the sort descriptor.  Test without the predicate, then without the sort descriptor, and see which causes the issue (or possibly both!).

Comment: apparently it's both but I really don't know why... do I need to test if messages is not nil too ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you will be able to get a fetched results controller to achieve what you want.  The predicate can be made to work:

```
predicate = NSPredicate(format: "user.userID = %@ AND messages.@count > 0", IOSUser.sharedInstance().userID)
```

But the sort descriptor is a lost cause: CoreData can only sort on (persistent) attributes.  One solution would be to add a persistent attribute (eg. `lastMessageDate`) to the `Session` entity.  You would obviously need to update this attribute whenever adding/deleting a message to/from the Session.

If you can live with a plain fetch, you could fetch `Message` objects with a predicate:

```
predicate = NSPredicate(format: "session.user.userID = %@", IOSUser.sharedInstance().userID)
```

and sort descriptor:

```
let dateSortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "date", ascending: false)
```

and then extract an array of distinct `Session` objects using

```
let sessionsArray = fetchResults.valueForKeyPath("@distinctUnionOfObjects.session")
```

(you might need to cast `fetchResults` as `NSArray`).

Comment: Let me try the fetch on Message with the distinct approach. I was thinking also about fetch properties. Don't you think is possible to create one in session retrieving the last message?

Comment: Do you have an idea why "AND messages[SIZE] > 0" makes the fetch crash too ?

Comment: "AND messages.@count != 0" seems to be working though... the doc is not correct?!?!

Comment: @Mikael The docs are pretty thin, and don't give the full picture on which platforms (iOS/OSX), versions, store-types (sqlite v in memory) etc the various features are supported.  I'm afraid I don't think fetch properties will yield any better solution.

Comment: I finally added a lastMessageDate attribute in Session and used the messages.@count to check if the keypath was empty... I don't understand why they say: use array[SIZE] in your predicate for keypath... It just crashes...